# Java, transparent JFrame under Canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas

I am trying to implement a fully transperent `JFrame` which carries a `Canvas` object. I tried to make the `JFrame`'s background transparent by calling `frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` but somehow `Canvas` does not show up anymore on the screen and does not draw my rectangle. However, if I comment out `setBackground` function it draws perfectly, but of course the `JFrame` is not transparent.

```
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

    frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.add(canvas);
    //frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.toFront();
```

The buffer strategy to draw a blue rectangle on Canvas.

```
public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0,0,800,800);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

When `setBackground` is commented : [image]
When `setBackground` is not commented : [image: image2]

Comment: Heavy weight components can't be transparent (or translucent), they are always opaque

Comment: I assume Canvas is heavyweight. However I am trying to make JFrame transparent not the Canvas. I saw a tutorial with JPanel in JFrame and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, Canvas is heavy weight. I suspect that the frame is transparent, but the canvas is covering it

Comment: If it is. Should not it be blue instead of JFrame color.

Comment: Seems like you've stumbled across another one of those reason not to mix heavy and light weight components :P

Comment: You want to draw on top of jFrame - is it right?

Comment: I want JFrame to contain my Canvas, and I want to draw on the Canvas but JFrame must be invisible Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but somehow Canvas does not show up anymore on the screen and does not draw my rectangle

I suspect that there is more going on in your code then we have access to, as I seem to be able to get it to work...oddly...

[image: Screen]

So, this basically sets up a translucent window (for testing, I've tested it an alpha of `0` and it still works), adds a smaller `Canvas` to it (so I can see the window) and draws and even smaller rectangle on top of that.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestPane pane = new TestPane();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.setSize(100, 100);
                frame.setResizable(true);
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0, 128));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.toFront();

                Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        pane.render();
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends Canvas {

        public void render() {
            BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
            if (bs == null) {
                createBufferStrategy(3);
                return;
            }
            Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 25);
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////
            g.dispose();
            bs.show();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(50, 50);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Would anyone care to enlighten on the reason for the downvote?  In what ways does it not answer the question been asked? What is it missing?  In what ways might it (and future answers) be improved? Seen as you've not seen fit to provide your owner answer I can only assume you don't have a good idea how to solve it either?

Comment: I did not give you the downvote Sir. I will try when I am home.

Comment: The anwer helped me to get the correct solution but you must delete buffer strategy and replace it with a classical paint override

Comment: @orkun It's not the who but the why, but I appreciate it ;)

Comment: @orkun I guess that all depends on what you are trying to achieve, if you want a translucent/transparent effect, then yes. But at least we've established that a `Canvas` can reside on a transparent frame without (significant) issues ;)

Comment: This example does not work for me. I just get a transparent red frame--nothing inside. Only if I change the `frame.setBackground()` to fully opaque do I see the Canvas. What JRE you running and on which OS? Also, which graphics drivers? Somehow I fear this might all play a part...

Comment: @Roland Was mostly like tested under Windows 7 and Java 7 or 8, but re-tested under MacOS Sierra and Java 8 without issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer Tested it on Windows 10 with j8u25 which gave me the issue I described above. Now I just tested it with Windows 7 j8u131 and it gave me a different issue: The `Canvas` is drawn this time but it's just plain grey--it doesn't draw the blue box from the `BufferStrategy` graphics. Could you please let me know which Windows & Java version you had this working on? Then I can test a little more :)

Comment: @Roland As I said in my original answer, I'm surprised it works at all, given how Canvas and BufferStratgey works, I've always wondered why someone would need a transparent window with canvas setup thus way

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm working on a video player with a custom UI. I want to include window shadows, and to do this, I to use per-pixel-translucency. The video playing is shown on a `JPanel`, but unfortunately, `JPanel` is significantly slower than a `Canvas` and can only do around 40 FPS running at 100% CPU. When I try with a `Canvas` it uses around 30% CPU and can hit 75 FPS (or higher). Ideally I would have a frame that allows per-pixel-translucency in combination with a `Canvas`. This is an issue I'm still actively looking to solve.